# How can I trigger a job checking the status of two other job?

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

I have three jobs.

1. First Parent job
2. Second Parent job
3. Child job

I want to trigger 'Child job' only after 'First Parent job' and 'Second Parent job' is done and succeeded. I  don't have any control over both the Parent jobs. Both can run any time in any order.

In short I have a child job which is depended on two parent jobs. I want to run this child job just after both the parent jobs are completed.

Please help me with the solution ! Can I have a plugin or Jenkins python APIs.

Comment: Can I ask for clarifications? You said both can run at any time and any order, but you need both to run in order to trigger the child job? So if one is running and finished successfully you shouldn't trigger the child job? does the parent jobs have any connection between them? are they aligned with the number of builds? (as in - P1 runs 4 times and P2 runs 2 times, would you wait for P2 to run 2 more times before triggering the child's job?)

Comment: @Dvir669
Parent jobs are not related. 
For Example :
Parent Job1 creates an installer A
Parent Job2 Creates another installer B
Child Job needs both the installer to build a suite of these installers(A and B).
So , Parent jobs can be completed any time.  Both the parent jobs are independent. 
I need a mechanism that child job accept one trigger from one Parent job and wait for the successful run of next parent job.

Comment: It seems like you just need the last successful installers from both jobs. I would have implemented it differently, but you can try looking in the "Build Triggers" section and mark: "Build after other projects are built" in your child job. It'll allow you you build the child job after the parents finishes successfully. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using jenkins pipeline plugin. Here is example code:

```
parallel firstJob: {
        node {
            echo "Build parent-job-1"
            build 'parent-job-1'
        }
    }, secondJob: {
        node {
            echo "Build parent-job-2"
            build 'parent-job-2'
        }
    }

node {    
    echo "Build child-job"
    build 'child-job'
}
```

Comment: I cant control Parent jobs . which is controlled by another team.

Comment: So maybe you can add in section build triggers: Build after other projects are built and add parent jobs.

Comment: I need both the parent job to be completed before triggering child job.